# WPF: DependencyProperty property binding issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am using a custom control, its expanded status relies on the parameter passed from outside. the code is below:

myControl.xaml:

```
<Expander x:Name="Expander" Grid.Row="1" IsExpanded="True">
```

myControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class myControl: UserControl{
public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandAllProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpandAll", typeof(bool), typeof(myControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsExpandAllChanged)));

public bool IsExpandAll
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandAllProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsExpandAllProperty, value);
            }
        }

private static void OnIsExpandAllChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            myControl rv = sender as myControl;                
            rv.Expander.IsExpanded = System.Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue.ToString());
        }
```

outside xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <view:myControl IsExpandAll="{Binding ExpandAllItems}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

outside viewModel:

```
 private bool _expandAllItems = true;
 public bool ExpandAllItems
    {
        get { return _expandAllItems; }
        set
        {
            _expandAllItems= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ExpandAllItems");
        }
    }
```

outside xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.ExpandAllItems= !vm.ExpandAllItems;
    }
```

I change the ExpandAllItems value using a button click event, but when debugging, I find that the IsExpandAll property setter is never invoked, the expander in myControl can't update.

Comment: how is `ExpandAllItems` defined?  and how do you change it using a button click event?

Comment: IsExpandAllRanks in XAML is different from IsExpandAll. Otherwise, when I try a similar piece of code the on change handler is hit but not the setter when I make it a bool? and bind to a togglebutton ischecked. Bindings don't use the setter. Depending on exactly what you're doing, that could be the explanation for why your setter isn't invoked.

Comment: @ASh, thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: @Andy, thanks, there is a typo. I've correct it.  I don't know  why the setter can't be invoked. How to make it works?

Comment: Bindings do not invoke the setter. Put your logic in the onchanged. Or call the setter explicitly in code.

Comment: @Andy, I tried, but even OnIsExpandAllChanged can't hit, in your test, OnIsExpandAllChanged can always hit?

Comment: Yes. I'll post my code so it's clearer.

Comment: `System.Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue.ToString())` looks rather odd, when you could simply write `(bool)e.NewValue`. Besides that, you don't actually need the PropertyChangedCallback at all. Just bind the Expander property like `<Expander ... IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpandAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">`

Comment: @Clemens thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a bit of code to explore what's going on here.
I've got a usercontrol and a togglebutton. 
Obviously, this is just an experiment so they don't do much.
Because I want something to drive change of the dp by binding I bind to ischecked on the togglebutton.
This is actually a bool? so I made my dp a bool? to match that.

In Mainwindow, just bind that togglebutton ischecked:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 IsExpandAll="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=IsChecked}"/>
        <ToggleButton Name="tb" Content="Expandall"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

My UserControl1 has just a grid in it - the only purpose is to explore this dp

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public bool? IsExpandAll
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(IsExpandAllProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(IsExpandAllProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandAllProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpandAll", typeof(bool?), typeof(UserControl1),   new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsExpandAllChanged)));

    private static void OnIsExpandAllChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 rv = sender as UserControl1;
        Debugger.Break();
       // rv.Expander.IsExpanded = System.Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
```

When I spin this up, it hits the break first because the dp is set.
Carry on...
Click the togglebutton and it hits the break again.
Remove that break point and put a break point on the setter.
This is never hit at all.
The reason for that is the setter is not used by bindings.

Comment: @Sarina What exactly did you take from this answer?

Comment: @Clemens, I think you are very proficient in wpf, I firstly need to resolve my problem, it took me several hours, I am a newer in this technic, and I thank Andy, he help me to implement it. and I really appreciate your comments, you give me clues,and it can help me to do more research,  I'll try it later.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Sarina I'm really just curious in which way this answer helped you exactly. Just the debugging?